# Accessing QMap of QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>>

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to write and initialize

```
QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>>
```

in Qt 5.10 ?

For example I want to do that

```
QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>> ee{"MAC", 0,0,};  // string, section 0, line 0
```

When I supply `Mac`, I need to retrieve the pair `0,0`

```
 eepromDictionary = QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>>{ {
                                                      "MAC", {0,0},
                                                      "IP", {0,0},
                                                      "Mask", {0,0},
                                                      "ID", {0,0},
                                                      "Gateway", {0,0},
                                                      "Date", {0,0}
                                                      }

                                                      };
```

Comment: i think it should be "{"MAC", {0,0}}"

Comment: Did you *try* what you want to do? How did it work? What problems did you have with it? What (if any) errors did you get? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please go through [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: still compiles error, not matching function call

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'QMap<QString, QPair<int, int> >::QMap(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Comment: I could be wrong, but i feel like it should be `ee{ {"MAC", {0,0} } }` as it's a list basically, and not `ee{"MAC", 0,0,}`, you are missing the "list"'s brackets, you are creating an element but not the list by initializing this way, at least (no jokes intented) i feel a lot like it's the problem here ?

Comment: it works with the list { { }}} , thanks

Comment: Nice, gonna make it an answer then :) ! be nice and upvote ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the [`QMap(initializer_list<pair<Key, T>>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#QMap-1) takes `pair<Key, T>` as it's elements. It should be sufficient to wrap each element in it's own braces. For example:

```
QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>> ee = {{"MAC", {0, 0}}}
```

If you were going to initialize a second element of `ee` you could extend the `initializer_list` like so: `{{"MAC", {0, 0}}, {"DONALDS", {0, 0}}}`

Answer (score 0):

By initializing this way: `ee{"MAC", {0,0} }` you are initializing only a list element, you are missing the List's brackets, doing it this way should solve the problem:

```
QMap<QString, QPair<int, int>> ee{ {"MAC", {0,0} } }
```

Comment: thanks, can you look at the edited question, tried to do it like you said, but I get compile error

Comment: As i said, {} is an element, if you want more elements, you need to put them into their own brackets, as the answer of Jonathan suggests :)